# php in background exec() function

Tags: php, process, exec

I made this script to test the execution of PHP as a background process

```
foreach($tests as $test) { 
   exec("php test.php ".$test["id"]); 
}
```

as suggested in [php process background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462951/php-process-background/4463064#4463064)
and [How to add large number of event notification reminder via Google Calendar API using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216925/how-to-add-large-number-of-event-notification-reminder-via-google-calendar-api-us) and [php execute a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)

But the script does not run faster than when it was all in one script without the addition of test.php.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar to a question I answered a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626860/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-in-the-background-after-a-form-is-submitted/4628279#4628279

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`exec()` will block until the process you're exec'ing has completed - in otherwords, you're basically running your 'test.php' as a subroutine. At bare minimum you need to add a `&` to the command line arguments, which would put that exec()'d process into the background:

```
exec("php test.php {$test['id']} &");
```

Comment: does not work the content of $test['id'] is only a number.
so the command looks like exec('php test.php &150');
is it correct?

Comment: Woops, sorry, should be `php test.php 150 &`. The ampersand has to be the last character. I'll fix up the answer.

Comment: According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), it also requires output redirection in order to run in the background. `php test.php 150 > /dev/null &`