# PHP: how to start a detached process?

Tags: php, linux, parallel-processing

Currently my solution is:

```
exec('php file.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

and in file.php

```
if (posix_getpid() != posix_getsid(getmypid()))
    posix_setsid();
```

is there any way I can do this just with exec?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe he posix_setsid example can help, but it uses fork().

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**No**, detaching can't be done with `exec()` directly (nor `shell_exec()` or `system()`, at least not without changing the command, and using third-party tool which does detach).

---

If you have the [pcntl extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) installed, it would be:

```
function detached_exec($cmd) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    switch($pid) {
         // fork errror
         case -1 : return false;

         // this code runs in child process
         case 0 :
             // obtain a new process group
             posix_setsid();
             // exec the command
             exec($cmd);
             break;

         // return the child pid in father
         default: 
             return $pid;
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$pid = detached_exec($cmd);
if($pid === FALSE) {
    echo 'exec failed';
}

// ... do some work ...

// Optionally, kill child process (if no longer required).
posix_kill($pid, SIGINT);
waitpid($pid, $status);

echo 'Child exited with ' . $status;
```

Comment: I do not want to daemonize the process nor do I need to fork it. I just need to start another php process that wouldn't receive SIGINT when the one who created it exits. (I'm not really sure how a daemon is different from a process that is detached from the terminal?)

Comment: Check my example again. Isn't it what you want? ;) The only difference to a daemon is that the does not run forever but will be killed on fathers exit.

Comment: Basically yes, but try implementing that in a simple function that returns true or false. (It MUST NOT block). And I don't want the new process to be killed, it will exit itself.

Comment: Yes it is :) Though I think it's an overkill to make a fork, so I think I'll stick with detaching the process when it starts.

Comment: What do you expect `exec()` does under the hood? It will start a shell (that's why you can use output redirection in commands) You may replace the `exec()` in child with the actual php code of the child.. (can be a function or a class method, ....) then you'll save the additional shell and the php-cli call and it would be best for performance

Comment: @hek2mgl Looking at the example in my answer, could you look into updating/deleting the first sentence in yours? Otherwise your solution looks very clean and feasible :)

Comment: @Philzen Yours is a working solution but it is more a shell script than a PHP script. The work of detaching the process is not done by the `exec()` function, it is done by nohup. But in was questioned whether the `exec()` function can do it. However yours is a good workaround if the pcntl extension isn't installed

Comment: "detaching the process is not done by the exec() function, it is done by nohup" - fair point you have there :)

Comment: If parent process won't exit immediately after fork the child process should [fork one more time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon) to prevent creating zombie.

Comment: @vvolodko Thanks for your hint! (and srry for my late reply) Will read through this and update my answer

Answer (score 9):

Provided your current user has sufficient permissions to do so this should be possible with `exec` and alike:

```
/*
/ Start your child (otherscript.php)
*/
function startMyScript() {
    exec('nohup php otherscript.php > nohup.out & > /dev/null');
}

/*
/ Kill the script (otherscript.php)
/ NB: only kills one process at the time, otherwise simply expand to 
/ loop over all complete exec() output rows
*/
function stopMyScript() {
    exec('ps a | grep otherscript.php | grep -v grep', $otherProcessInfo);
    $otherProcessInfo = array_filter(explode(' ', $otherProcessInfo[0]));
    $otherProcessId = $otherProcessInfo[0];
    exec("kill $otherProcessId");
}

// ensure child is killed when parent php script / process exits
register_shutdown_function('stopMyScript');

startMyScript();
```

Comment: Please do **not** do this ever again: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3201462 This is absolutely not how Stack Overflow works. You are way, **way** out of line, crossing out somebody else's answer and pointing their answer to your own.

Comment: Apologies - no pun intended. I was under the impression S.O. was very serious about not having incorrect information here, thus i merely suggested to remove hek2mgl's info that this couldn't be done with exec() function.

Comment: Voting is the way we sort content here.

Comment: This is a good workaround if the pcntl extension isn't available +1