# Multiple exec commands php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php in background exec() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646788/php-in-background-exec-function)

I am trying to run two exec commands from PHP. One is a script that might run for a few minutes and there can only be once instance of it. The second exec just checks if the first process is running and either lets you run it again or redirects you. The code is something like this.

This is the main process

```
$command = '/home/user/active/Nem-Swd.elf 30 > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!';
```

This is the process that checks if the other one is running already.

```
exec("ps ax | grep $name 2>&1", $output);
```

I know that in the php API it says :

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

But I don't understand what that implies.

Comment: What that means is that you need to redirect output to file (text file, xml file, ect) in order for your exec statement to continue running after the PHP program exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that if you run the exec command without re-routing its output, your current PHP script will wait for that command to finish before terminating the script.  Since you are routing the output to standard out, I believe you should be ok.  If you just ran `exec($commandJob)` you then would run into this problem.

---

Seems that this question has already been answered:
[php in background exec() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646788/php-in-background-exec-function)

At a minimum (for example) you need to do this to make it run in the background:
`exec("php test.php &");`

---

There are other ways to start processes that might be worth looking into as well:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

Comment: The why is it still waiting until the first process completes?

Comment: so you run two execs in a row, but the second one never runs?

Comment: The second one runs only when the first one is complete.

Comment: What happens if you do something like `exec($commandJob.' > command.out')`?

Comment: same thing it waits until the first one is finished.

Comment: I have added the full command now, there is an ampersand before the echo. If I run this in the terminal it works exactly like it's supposed to do so. When php is executing it, it is not running in the background.

Comment: Try running is like this? `exec('/home/user/active/Nem-Swd.elf 30 &')`

Comment: Yea i tried that with no success php still waits until it is over before running the second process. On top of it that shouldnt work technically since you have to redirect the output. which I tried with exec('/home/user/active/Nem-Swd.elf 30 & 2>&1); with no success.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't do that. I am running php and apache on a circuit board so it will be a pain to cross compile php with pcntl enabled.

Comment: maybe you need to use something like one of these: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

Comment: It worked with popen thanks a lot. So basically I used `popen('/home/user/active/Nem-Swd.elf &','r');`