# Running process in background with PHP using exec?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php in background exec() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646788/php-in-background-exec-function)

After a certain script runs on website I want to do a bit of processing in the background which could take a little long to run on the page request.
I heard you can do this by using the exec() method to run a PHP script.
If this is a good way to do it how do I pass a query string to PHP script with the exec() method?

EDIT:
It's not a duplicate because the post you're referring to doesn't deal with my question about query string/argument passing.

Comment: What do you mean by "query string" -- when using PHP on the command line, instead of through apache, there is no _GET array. You deal with the $args array of command-line arguments. These are passed on the command line after the script name itself, with spaces separating them.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm sorry I've never ran PHP on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a PHP script in the background using PHP, then you can do the following:

```
$command = "php -d max_execution_time=50 -f myfile.php '".$param."' >/dev/null &";
exec($command);
```

$param is a variable you want to pass into the file.

Comment: Using `exec()` in this fashion can be dangerous if `$param` was supplied from (or improperly derived from) user-supplied input. See [Wikipedia's notes on shell injection vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_injection#Shell_injection) for details.

Comment: Yeah for sure.. I was assuming he was setting the value himself like $param = "idx" for example

Comment: Since you took care to use `max_execution_time` I figured _your_ code would be fine -- but not everyone reading this would know that already. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your script runs in the background and not in a terminal, try [ignore_user_abort( TRUE )](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php); execution flow continues until execution is complete, and not when the tab or window or network connection is closed.