# How to install crontab for specific user via php

Tags: php, shell, command, cron

I'm currently programming a web interface in PHP (5.3) for handling timings and installing cronjobs as a simple interface for managing cronjobs. The web server is on the same server as the cron service. I've managed to save the crontab to a file to exchange it for a specific user on the system. Now I have the problem that php is running with a different user than the crontab should be installed for.
In addition I need to be able to define the cron-user in my web interface via an input field.

I've tried to execute a shell command via PHP `crontab -u MyCronuser MyCrontab` but the PHP user does not have privileges for using -u parameter (and I'm not allowed to change this)
So next thought was to do something like `su cronUser` but there is no -p parameter so I cannot handle over the password for login. I tried to chain the commands like `su cronuser && echo 'MyPassword'` but it didn't work and I did not find any solution via Google for logging into shell with different users with PHP. Is there a way for doing so?
Using sudo for performing as root user without password is also not an option since I'm not allowed to activate these permissions.

Is there any solution I might have missed? Maybe a different approach to my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer falls under the different approach category and might not be helpful for you.  I have built several cron systems that operate in the following manner.

1) Setup a cron to run every minutes and call a php file (for example cron.php)
2) cron.php will pull data from a database table that indicates what scripts need to run and at what interval
3) cron executes the appropriate scripts - handles errors etc.

I'm not sure what your need is for users but it should be trivial to add that data to the database table.

Comment: Thanks für your answer. So you would suggest some kind of virtual cron-service? But what about speed and resources if you have a php script every minute which reads database tables and run scripts? Do you have any experience with that? And what if 2 or more jobs are at the same time? With just one php cronjob this is not possible to handle, one would be after the second stoped.

Comment: Overhead has never been an issue at all.  If it was you could cache the database values and have them update every day.  In my code I prefer to only have one script running at a time but it is trivial to allow multiple to run : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646788/php-in-background-exec-function