# Exec within a for loop - execute multiple instances

Tags: php

How can you run multiple exec instances from a for loop and run them separately (i.e. not have one dependent on another finishing before starting another)? I have the following code which is hopefully self explanatory:

```
for ($i = 0;$i < 5;$i++){
    exec('START '.$path.' '.PATH.'spawn.php "'."$type,$core".'"');
}
```

I have looked at [php in background exec() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646788) but it isn't a duplicate as I am using the START command and adding an & did not fix it.

I have tried /B as an option but additionally this didn't work - it just ran it in the background.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 2008 R2 SP1 :)

Comment: Okey the reason the & did not work is because that's for a Unix OS. Do you want the processes the run in parallel or one after the other?

Comment: All at the same time - in parallel. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under windows you will need to do it a bit differently.

```
$runCommand = 'calc.exe';
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run($runCommand, 7, false);
```

This should help explain it http://www.somacon.com/p395.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#43917

Comment: Brilliant. Although I still need to tweak my code WScript.Shell through COM worked great. Thanks