# How to run multiple command with exec in php

Tags: php, bash

I need to run 2 command after each other with `exec` but it won't run.

## Code

```
$command1 = 'cd '.$destination.''; //open destination folder (e.g. public_html)
$command2 = 'git clone '.$repos->repository.''; //make clone

$sshConnection1 = exec($command1); // run first command(open folder)
$sshConnection = exec($command2); //run second command (make clone)
```

Before I create this question I read some of suggested topics like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646788/php-in-background-exec-function). to add `"&"` etc. but no luck.

**Please tell me what should I do in order to run both commands successfully.**

Comment: @Amessihel but they won't , I checked first command with `dd($sshConnection1);` and it returns `false`

Comment: How about `exec("cd $destination && git clone ...")`

Comment: @KarstenKoop thanks dude it works, please share it as answer, i'll so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put both commands into one `exec()` call by combining them with `&&`:

```
exec("cd $destination && git clone {$repos->repository}");
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like PHP's `exec` forks at some point, so that `cd` isn't going to affect the parent process.

```
php > echo getcwd();
/home/nchambers
php > exec("cd ..");
php > echo getcwd();
/home/nchambers
php > echo exec("pwd");
/home/nchambers
php > exec("cd ..");
php > echo exec("pwd");
/home/nchambers
php >
```

Also, `git clone` can take a destination directory to write to. I can't say why your commands are failing without more information, but just some initial problems with what you're trying to run.